# maven-release-plugin automatically run a script before commit

Tags: maven, docker, maven-release-plugin

I was wondering if it would be possible to make the `maven-release-plugin` run a specific script before the commit of the new tag.

The reason is, I have a Dockerfile that I want to update with the new version of my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`completionGoals`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#completionGoals) option of the `release:perform` goal:

> Goals to run on completion of the preparation step, after transformation back to the next development version but before committing. Space delimited.

And have the [`maven-exec-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) execute your script via its [`exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) goal.

A simple example would be as following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ....
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- example: executing an hello message on Windows console -->
                <executable>cmd</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>/C</argument>
                    <argument>echo</argument>
                    <argument>hello</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                ...
                <completionGoals>exec:exec</completionGoals>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note the value of the `completionGoals` above, we actually telling Maven to also execute the `exec` plugin and its `exec` goal, which will then pick up our global configuration as above.

In your case the exec configuration above would be something like:

```
<configuration>
    <executable>your-script</executable>
    <!-- optional -->
    <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
    <arguments>
        <argument>-X</argument>
        <argument>myproject:dist</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

---

Depending on the exact point of release preparation, you could also consider to use the additional [`preparationGoals`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#preparationGoals) configuration option instead:

> Goals to run as part of the preparation step, after transformation but before committing. Space delimited.

Which has a default value of `clean verify`, in this case would then be `clean verify exec:exec`.

Comment: I would recomment to have this separated cause maven is not for Deployment etc. and don't integrate it into the build furthermore this makes you build environment dependent...

Comment: @khmarbaise good point, this should not be part of the maven build, at worst should be defined in a profile.

Comment: Well Thanks that's interesting and it seems to work. Unfortunately with a multi module project, the completionGoal is executed for each sub-module. I'll comme back here if I find how to overcome that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like @dimatteo said, but I encourage you to NOT do this, as docker and maven are two tools for two differents purposes.

If you want to automate these 2 actions, use something (shell, jenkins, ...) which will launch maven then docker.

Comment: I think you're right about that. The problem is, I need to modify this Dockerfile so the continuous delivery process can be done correctly by pointing to the right jar. Therefore I thought modifying it wouldn't be such a bad approach.